# Romance manga where friends go back in time with keys to save a girl from her own suicide

Tags: story-identification, manga

I saw a romance and fiction manga one year ago and I can't remember the name of it.

It's about a girl that falls in love with her sisters' boyfriend and the story repeats because her friends go back in time with some keys to save her because she tries to commit suicide.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: How did the keys help to stop her from committing suicide?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the manga [*Katayoku no Labyrinth*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/65489/Katayoku_no_Labyrinth).  I've seen the title also translated as "Henyoku no Labyrinth", probably due to a translation error, as the first kanji in the title can be read as kata or hen, but the word is definitely katayoku.

I recall the protagonist is in love with her sister's boyfriend, and she ends up traveling back in time using a magical key.